# converting base64 to GUIDs/UUIDs in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, base64, guid

I've been trying to find a way to decode a base64 column in a bigquery table to a GUID/UUID. Does anyone know of a function in SQL that I can do this with or would I have to use a different language than SQL.

Comment: do you have any sample data to verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If understand correctly, `SELECT FROM_BASE64(guid_column) AS id` should do it for you.